# How to create empty datetime format in mysql

Tags: mysql, datagrid

The `mysql` default `datetime` format when null is `1970-01-01 07:00:00`

Is it possible to have an empty string (" ") instead of a null when loading it into a data grid? It would behave as an *empty* column/cell.

Comment: `1970-01-01 07:00:00` is just the unix epoch at Timezone +700 it's not a mysql null.

Comment: Mysql does not like null datetimes

Comment: If you really need an empty string in your datagrid, convert the `datetime` to `varchar` {use [DATE_FORMAT()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format)} and convert it back to `datetime` whenever needed.